# Maturation temperature (when SG stabilizes)

Tags: fermentation, conditioning, maturation

Some guys recommend to increase the temperature once the fermentation finished, and so, "start" the maturation in a higher temperature. Others say the inverse, to reduce the temperature.

I already tried the 2 techniques, but changing only among 2C to 4C degrees (35F to 37F), and I cannot get a noticeable difference between than.

What is the care we need to have with the temperature when the maturation starts (FG stabilizes) ? Keep it, increase it, or reduce it ?

**EDIT - Defining "maturation":** 
Maturation, secondary fermentation, conditioning, aging, in English some people use one, others use another. But I'm referring to the phase just after SG doesn't change anymore (about 3-4 days in Ales) and the yeasts start to eat 'undesired compounds', in Portuguese its's called solely "maturation".

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing two different things.  the reason to raise the temp toward the end of fermentation is to make sure the yeast is active enough to finish the fermentation.  That's commonly done with both ales and lagers.  as an example, I ferment most ales around 63F, but after 5-7 days at that temp I raise it to make sure fermentation is done.  after that, I crash the temp down to around 35F to begin cold conditioning the beer.  Your term "maturation" is kind of hazy, but I think you;re referring to this cold conditioning phase.  For long term aging, a cooler temp is always preferred to reduce the effects of staling.

Comment: Considering my edit about the term "maturation", there're those who argue that the best benefits can be obtained reducing the temperature, other increasing temperature, or keeping temperature, for between 5 to 15 days after SG stabilizes (in Ale). What about the best temperature adjust to use in that phase ?

Comment: Given your revised definition, after 3-4 days it's a good idea to let the temperature rise to ensure complete fermentation, as in my original post.  For most yeast strains, that means getting the temp to the 70-74F range, although for some strains of saison yeast it could be 80-90F.  Besides completing fermentation, the increased yeast activity can also "clean up" undesirable flavors in your beer.  After that, for long term aging (sometimes also referred to as "maturation"), cooler temps are better and temps of 45-55F work well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a lager? It sounds like you are describing a cold crash. Ageing ales is usually done at ambient temp, although they may benefit from ageing in a keg at serving temps. Lagers age at lager temps (usually 10F/5.5C degrees F cooler than fermentation). A typical lager schedule might be

```
ferment at 50-55F, 2 weeks
rest at 65F, 2 days
lager at 45F 2 months
lager at 35F for 2 months (Is this what you are calling maturation??)
```